# with ember cli, how to specify different layout for a component within POD structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a a basic ember cli app with a component, and I wanted to specify different layoutName to the component based on a property passed to it. I am not sure how to achieve this. Right now I just want to know how to specify a templateName to a known template to get started. This is what I tried:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    layoutName: null,

    initialize: function() {
        this.set('layoutName', 'pi/pods/components/questions/single-select/standard-layout');
    }.on('init')

});
```

and my folder structure looks like:

```
app
|-pods
    |-components
              |-questions
                    |-single-select
                            |-component.js
                            |-template.hbs//just has {{yield}}
                            |-standard-layout.hbs//says hello
```

JUST A THOUGHT : This may be a new question itself - before we used jsbin to collaborate but now how can we achieve same when we are building stuff with ember-cli!!

**SOLUTION :**
 as per @sunrize920 suggestion, I had to break out of POD structure a bit. So the working solution looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    layoutName: null,

    initialize: function() {
        this.set('layoutName', 'components/questions/single-select/standard-layout');           
    }.on('init')

});
```

And then my folder structure looks like this:

```
dev-folder
    |-app
        |-pods
            |-components
                      |-questions
                            |-single-select
                                    |-component.js
                                    |-standard-layout
                                         |-template.hbs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So component's and layout don't exactly work out of the box like you are expecting. Lets say we have component called `my-component`. Ember interprets the template you define at `templates/components/my-component` as the layout and anything you wrap the component around via block syntax: `{{#my-compenent}}{{/my-component}}`as the component's template. Look at this [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zujoqadami/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to see what I mean.

What I am talking about isn't using pod syntax, but I would imagine that if you did not define the `template.hbs` or whatever the convention is that ember-cli uses to resolve the components template, you should be able to pass a `layoutName` and `templateName` to your component. Hope that works

Answer (score 1):

As of Ember 2.3.0 (and perhaps before), it is *not* possible to set `layout` or `layoutName` in the component's `init` or in an `on('init')` handler to override the template. If there is a template, it will be used regardless of the layout specified in the component.js.

If you have the option to extend the component and omit the template, then the above technique will work. If instead you need to reopen and existing component, as of now you appear to be out-of-luck. Hopefully this will change in the future.